# unittest.test namespace doesn't exist in linux python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to port a python module, that has up until now been developed strictly on Windows, to linux. When running the unit test I got this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unittest.test'
```

If I go into the python `/lib/unittest` path, the `unittest.test` directory doesn't exist, which seems odd since it exists in the [main python repo](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/unittest).

I have tried installing python from scratch on several different linux machines and have even tried clean docker containers, but that directory is always missing. It exists in all the windows installations, and I don't see anything to indicate that this is a windows-only module.

Am I missing something obvious?

[image: missing test directory]

Edit: Here is the console output from a fresh Debian docker image where I installed python3 through apt-get.

```
root@10472a7cd1fd:/# python3 --version
Python 3.5.3
root@10472a7cd1fd:/# python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import unittest.test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'unittest.test'
>>>
```

Edit2:

Here's an instance of the code I'm porting that makes use of this namespace.

```
import unittest
from unittest.test.testmock.support import is_instance
...
self.assertTrue(is_instance(data.getType(), IntType))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPython's [Lib/unittest/test](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/unittest/test) is a directory containing the tests for unittest itself ([..yo dawg!](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/68058912/yo-dawg-i-heard-you-like-testing-so-i-suggest-you-test-your-tests-before-testing-your-test-case-so-y.jpg)).  It's not a sub-package, and you don't need that installed to *use* unittest.

You likely just want the top-level `unittest` namespace, e.g.

```
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
```

Comment: doh! ok then.... but the project code I'm working with is making use of [is_instance](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c89b22175807d64c47b598163b804b5dc005d1bb/Lib/unittest/test/testmock/support.py#L1) which is in `unittest/test/testmock/support.py` If that no longer exists, then I'm unsure what to replace it with.

Comment: As a wild guess, somebody in your project accidentally typo `is_instance` when they actually meant to use `isinstance` and then their IDE auto-completed an import statement.  PyCharm in particular has a pretty bogus auto-import feature.